# Postgresql Selective replication

Tags: postgresql, replication

I am trying to figure out how to replicate a postgres database with sensitive data content into a database in another server and would like to run some updates on some rows so that sensitive data are randomized. I didn't find any solution with Postgres' replication hot standby.

Is it possible to achieve this with only Postgres or I would need some external services like Slony-l?

Thanks

Comment: Check pg_logical extension. I think it can do that.